# Getting java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError while deploying app to jboss server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy the spring boot applciation to jboss 7.4 server and i amd getting the error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
Stacktrace below .. could someone pelase help. Thank you!

MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."p8service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."p8service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service         at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)         at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)         at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener         at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)         at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)         at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)         at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.InjectionTargets.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargets.java:64)         at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:121)         at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)         at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)         ... 6 more Caused by: **java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet and javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener disagree on InnerClasses attribute        **

I tried searching in google and did not find solution. Am expecting the solution

Comment: Do you have two copies of servlet.jar?